# how can I share my screen cast when click my button?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file, screensharing

I write this codes: when click my share button , yes my screen photo save to sd card but when ı press share on facebook or bluetooth it says it doesn t find.if I select photo manually I can share but ı want to share my screen photo when ı click share button? how can ı do this?

```
mylayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);




// this is the important code :)
// Without it the view will have a
// dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will
// be null




mylayout.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
//v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
mylayout.layout(0, 0, mylayout.getWidth(), mylayout.getHeight());
mylayout.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(mylayout.getDrawingCache());
mylayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); //




if (bm != null) {
    try {
        String  path2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(path2, "screentest.jpg");
        pathim=file.getPath();
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);




        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();




        Log.e("ImagePath", "Image Path : "
                + MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(),
                        file.getName(), file.getName()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(pathim);


sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share with"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change this line:

```
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(pathim);
```

into:

```
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

and move `File file` declaration into outside `if()`

Comment: can you say how I tag this image on facebook same time

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by tag image on facebook.

Comment: Tagging image in face ,I mean in facebook when upload an image , you can tag photo your friends. can ı tell you?

Comment: oh, you need to incorporate facebook api into your java. I never done that, sorry.

Comment: Icant  ask question anymore . Can ı ask again? please let me